# Get words from a file using groovy

Tags: groovy

Using groovy how can I get the words/texts from a file which enclosed with parentheses.

Example:

> George (a programmer) used to think much.

words to get: `a programmer`

Comment: I tried using something like this: `str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1,str.indexOf(')'))`

Comment: You can edit your answer to add the code. I just tested your code and it worked. You have to be more specific describing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example program solving the issue:

```
String inp = 'George (a programmer) used to think much.'
def matcher = inp =~ /\(([^\)]+)\)/   // Try to find a match
if (matcher) {    // Something found
  String str = matcher[0][1]     // Get the 1st capture group
  printf("Found: %s.\n", str)
  def words = str.tokenize()     // Create a list of words
  words.eachWithIndex{ it, i -> printf("%d: %s.\n", i, it)}
} else {
  print("Not found")
}
```

Note the meaning of parentheses in the regular expression:

- Outer (backslash quoted) parentheses are *literal* parentheses (we are
  looking for these chars).
- Unquoted parentheses (between them) are *delimiters* of the capture group.
- The remaining (quoted) closing parenthesis between them is the char
  that should **not** be present within the capture group.